# How to find the points of hausdorff_distance() in Shapely?

Tags: python, shapely

The Shapely [`hausdorff_distance()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.hausdorff_distance) function returns a single (scalar) value.

Is there a way to get the/a pair of points on both geometries that fit this distance?
Similar to how we have [`nearest_points()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#nearest-points) relative to [`distance()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.distance).